# Validate age (>18) Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I working on this form that has to be filled only by those over 18 years old. I was wondering if is possible to ask for the date of birth or the age in the first question and if is over 18 then the rest of the form is unlocked, if not a warning messages appears, something like "You must be over 18 to participate".

Answer (score 5):

**Yes it is possible**.

What you would need to do is this:

1. Create a section right at the beginning having just **one multiple choice question and make it required**.
2. Create a second section (right under it) with **NO questions**. Just a Title (*Sorry*) and a description (*You must be over 18 to participate.*) and name/fill them with whatever you like e.g: Title "*Sorry*", description "*You must be over 18 to participate*".
3. Use the "*Go to section based on answer*" feature and direct accordingly.
4. Enjoy.

Please have a look at the following image.

[image: over 18]

I hope it makes sense to you.

I have also created a demo form for you to try out, that you can find [here](https://forms.gle/QQvGMpThcq7kiMFt5).

> #### Edit
>
> Made a mistake and the form was set to private. It is now corrected.