# How to validate a date in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, date, data-validation

[Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) include the possibility to perform some sort of validation on user input for checkboxes and text; the functionality is available very easily both via the UI and the API. Unfortunately, it seems that there no support for any sort of validation on date input fields. The [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) does not include it, and I don't see any callback/trigger that I can use for this purpose.

More specifically, my form contains a field in which the user is requested to input their birthdate, and the form can be submitted only if their age lies in a certain interval (otherwise an error message of some sort should be displayed, possibly directly below the input field like in the other existing validations). All this should go in a form created with the Google Form creation UI.

Is there a way to do it? I don't mind if this is a client-only check, since this is not mission-critical and my users won't be experts actively trying to break it. And, of course, I don't mind writing Javascript / Google Apps script code for this purpose.

(Incidentally, in the API documentation for a [DateItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-item) I don't even see a function to return the date that the user has chosen, which I would need to implement this.)

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626802/google-apps-script-validating-dates-in-form --- the answer is not particularly useful: it shows a simple validation function, but does not describe how to bind it to a google form, which is the nontrivial part.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231531/form-validation-before-submission Not a Google Form, but a Google Apps Script, which is something else entirely (and more difficult to modify at need).
- [Validate age (>18) Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105310/validate-age-18-google-forms) Not really date validation, just a workaround.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350114/form-validation-using-client-handler-why-does-input-sequence-order-change-the Again google forms "re-invented" as a Google app. It seems to me that on a Google Form created with the UI I don't have available the object ids that I need to do something similar.

Comment: _"...[Validate age (>18) Google Forms?](https://forms.gle/QQvGMpThcq7kiMFt5) Not really date validation, just a workaround..."_. A **working workaround** in my opinion _(... my form contains a field in which the user is requested to input their birthdate, and the form can be submitted only if their age lies in a certain interval...)_. After all, validation is based on the submitter's discretion in providing their real age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to Short text, paragraph and checkbox questions, Google Forms doesn't have a way to validate input through date questions. Ref. [Set rules for your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en)

There is no way to add client-side code to the respondent view of Google Forms but you could create a web form that submit form data to the Google Form back-end.

Some "early" approaches copy the source code of the respondent view, adapt it to add client-side features like input validation of change the form presentation. Example of this "early approach" [How to style Google Forms](https://morningstudio.com.au/blog/2013/06/how-to-style-google-forms/). NOTE: This works with the "old" Google Forms.

Another alternative is to create a totally independent web form. You could use the Google Apps Script HTML Service for this or other tools.

NOTE: In a strict sense, Google Forms doesn't have an API contrary as occurs with Google Sheets .

Answer (score -1):

I feel the only way out to accomplish it is to create 3 short answer fields (one each for date, month and year), and apply validation rules to each numeric entry.

HTH